# Flask SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many StaleDataError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I have a two classes which share a relationship through an association table. When I try to delete a row in the one of the tables. I see the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError
StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'tags' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 2 were matched.
```

Here are my models:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
)

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
                       backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<title %r>' % self.title


class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
```

An here is the code I run to delete:

```
def remove_tag(tag_id):
    tag = Tag.query.get(tag_id)
    for post in tag.posts:
        p = Post.query.get(post.id)
        p.tags.remove(tag)
db.session.delete(tag)
db.session.commit()
```

I have tried a striped-down version of this code, outside of this app, in a standalone test, db and environment. And, it works as expected removing the tag and associated table row.

What I would like to know, if possible:

- How did I get in the situation of a StaleDataError ?
- Why does it match more than one row, when my query to .all() doesn't show multiple uses?
- How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Best,
Edward

Comment: I fixed some indentation in your example, but left `remove_tag()` untouched, though it seems to have some errors as well. Could you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an epiphany!

> How did I get in the situation of a StaleDataError ?

When testing my edit Post page I did many POST of the same post to the database.

> Why does it match more than one row, when my query to .all() doesn't show multiple uses?

My testing created multiple entries in the association table. In other words I had `(tag.id= 1, post.id=1)` multiple times.

> How can I prevent this from happening?

Add Unique Constraint to the association table to stop multiple entries to your DB. I also added checks in my view to stop multiple entries.

```
tags = db.Table(
    'tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id')),
    db.UniqueConstraint('tag_id', 'post_id', name='UC_tag_id_post_id')
)
```

Migrate your DB.

If your using SQlite and Alembic you will most likely encounter this error: "No support for ALTER of constraints in SQLite dialect". More on this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/61).

In short, if this is a development Database it is easier to delete your DB. If your in a production environment, perhaps you should consider a data migration and switch to another engine.

Answer (score 0):

What if I cannot modify the tags and post db model(when I am using opensource project that db migrate may cause lots of problems)?

I solved this problem by clean the `tags` that related to the `post_id`, and then reset the `post.tags = []`, lastly, delete the post
 item.

```
1.
sql = text('delete from tags where post_id = %s' % post_id)
db.engine.execute(sql)

2.
post.tags = []
db.session.merge(post)
db.session.commit()

3.
db.session.delete(post)
db.session.commit()
```